# dice roll simulation in python

Tags: python, dice

I am writing a program that is to repeatedly roll two dice until the user input target value is reached. I can not figure out how to make the dice roll happen repeatedly. Please, help...

```
from random import randrange
print ("This program rolls two 6-sided dice until their sum is a given target value.")
input = int (input("Enter the target sum to roll for:"))

#def main():

dice1 = randrange (1,7)

dice2 = randrange (1,7)

sumofRoll = dice1 + dice2

output = "Roll: {} and {}, sum is {}".format (dice1,dice2,sumofRoll)
print (output)

if sumofRoll == input:
    print ("All done!!")
if sumofRoll != input:


#how do I make this repeatedly run until input number is reached?!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working code which takes care of invalid sum entered as input as well. The sum of two dice rolls cannot be either less than 2 or more than 13. So a check for this condition makes your code slightly more robust. You need to initialize `sumofRoll = 0` before entering the `while` loop as this would be needed to first enter the while loop. The value of 0 is a safe value because we excluded the value of `0` entered by user to be a valid sum.

```
from random import randrange 
print ("This program rolls two 6-sided dice until their sum is a given target value.") 
input_sum = int(input("Enter the target sum to roll for:"))

def main():
    sumofRoll = 0
    if input_sum < 2 or input_sum > 13:
        print ("Enter a valid sum of dices")
        return
    while sumofRoll != input_sum:
        dice1 = randrange (1,7)
        dice2 = randrange (1,7)
        sumofRoll = dice1 + dice2
        output = "Roll: {} and {}, sum is {}".format (dice1,dice2,sumofRoll) 
        print (output)
        if sumofRoll == input_sum: 
            print ("All done!!") 

main()
```

---

```
This program rolls two 6-sided dice until their sum is a given target value.
Enter the target sum to roll for:10
Roll: 3 and 5, sum is 8
Roll: 6 and 6, sum is 12
Roll: 5 and 1, sum is 6
Roll: 2 and 5, sum is 7
Roll: 6 and 6, sum is 12
Roll: 3 and 5, sum is 8
Roll: 1 and 2, sum is 3
Roll: 6 and 4, sum is 10
All done!!
```

Answer (score 1):

I took your game and added some elements for you to peek through.  One is you could use `random.choice` and select from a `die` list instead of generating new random ints repeatedly.  Second you can use a `try/except` block to only accept an `int` and one that is within the range of `(2, 13)`. Next we can add a `roll_count` to track the amount of `rolls` to hit our target.  Our `while` loop will continue until `target == roll_sum` and then we can `print` our results.

```
from random import choice

die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print('This program rolls two 6-sided dice until their sum is a given target.')
target = 0
while target not in range(2, 13):
    try:
        target = int(input('Enter the target sum to roll (2- 12): '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a target between 2 and 12')

roll_sum = 0
roll_count = 0

while target != roll_sum:

    die_1 = choice(die)
    die_2 = choice(die)
    roll_sum = die_1 + die_2
    roll_count += 1
    print('You rolled a total of {}'.format(roll_sum))

print('You hit your target {} in {} rolls'.format(target, roll_count))
```

> ```
> ...
> You rolled a total of 4
> You rolled a total of 12
> You hit your target 12 in 29 rolls
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple *while* loop:

```
sumofRoll = -1; #a starting value!
while sumofRoll != input:
  #Put the code that updates the sumofRoll variable here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
while(sumOfRoll != input):
    dice1 = randrange(1,7)
    dice2 = rangrange(1,7)
    count = count + 1
    sumOfRoll = dice1 + dice2
print("sum = %s, took %s tries" % (sumOfRoll, count))
```

Comment: During the first iteration, you will have an error because `sumOfRoll` is not defined for the first check when you enter the while loop

Comment: To help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question

Comment: sorry, honestly this wasn't intended to be complete/functional code. the other answers had already fairly explained why to use a while loop. Next time though, I'll add more.

Answer (score 0):

Use a do while statement

```
do:
dice1=randrange(1,7)
...
while(sumofroll != input)
print("all done")
```